# Dual JK Flip-Flop Toogle Feature

Tags: clock, flipflop, counter, display, binary

I'm trying to make an 8-bit Display using 4 seven segment displays being driven by a single EEPROM [(like in this video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dLh1n2dErzE&t=592s).  From the video, I used the design of the 555 timer and a dual JK flip-flop to count 0 to 3.  The clock works, however, when I wire the flip-flop in the same way as is done in the video (Both presets, clears, Js and Ks high and connect the clock to the clock1 pin and the clock2 to the output of the first flip-flop)
[image: Circuit Diagram]
The two LEDs do not count up in binary as they do in the video instead, they both stay on.

I noticed that there are a few differences between the datasheets of the flip-flop I bought (CD4027BE) and the flip-flop he has.

1. On his datasheet, he has two preset pins and two clear pins whereas
   I have two set pins and two reset pins (although I do not think this
   is anything major)
2. On his datasheet, he has a toggle feature in the feature table where
       as in the datasheet I have, there is not a feature table.

So my question is have I bought the wrong flip-flop or am I wiring it incorrectly and if I have bought the wrong flip-flop can I make it work with this flip flop?

Additionally, the desired output is:

0,0 - 0,1 - 1,0 - 1,1 and repeat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TI data sheet for a CD4027B part shows this function table:

[image]

From this the immediate thing to notice is that the SET and RESET pins need to be connected to GND to keep them from having any action.

You can also observe that by connecting both the J and K inputs to a high level will cause the flip-flop to toggle its outputs at each clock rising edge.

Lastly if you want it to count binary in the manner stated you will want to connect the CLK2 pin to the Q1_NOT pin instead of the Q1 pin.

Another thing you need to put suitably sized resistors in series with the LEDs to limit the current to a safe level....both to protect the LEDs and the outputs of the flip-flop.

Comment: Doing what you have said outputs 1,0 consistently.

Comment: Just to clarify, you have all J and K inputs connected to VCC and all Set and  Reset connected to GND?

Comment: yes j1,j2,k1,k2 high and set1,set2,reset1,reset2 to gnd and I swaped the clock for a button

Comment: How is the clock button wired? Is the clock signal pulled to the correct state when not pressed? Is it debounced?

Comment: I just got it to work by setting the clock signal manually and it counted through properly so it must be the clock that is broken.

Comment: @Dan - No, the clock is not broken. It's just that without a debouncing circuit mechanical switches are noted for noisy operation. Inside the switch are two metal contacts. When they meet (the switch is closed), the two pieces of metal literally bounce a few times before coming to a rest, and the IC is fast enough to detect these bounces as separate clock pulses.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Yeah you are right I have it working with the clock now but I could trigger a clock pulse by moving my foot on and off the ground when touching the insulation of the wire, it's that sensative.